# Install Mac OS X via network across different subnets

Tags: macos, netboot

We have more than 70 subnets and lots of switches. I want to install Mac OS X to client computers. By the way the computer may have an operating system installed or not. I want to put an Apple Server in one place and all clients install Mac OS X from there. In the local network everything is fine but in a different subnet net install does not work. I searched some techniques but I think they are not for us. 
For example my Mac OS server's IP is 10.10.4.40  and the destination computer's IP is 10.10.12.23

Also our switches' configs are fine for netboot/netinstall (portfast and etc.)
But our technicians says "Computer cannot see the OS X Server".

I also read bootpd, Apple shell script solution vs. but the main problem is destination computer may not have operating system.

Please give me easy way to do it.

Comment: If your switches'/routers' configs were fine everything would work. Please add some details about your network devices like config/models:

Comment: We have different switches, like cisco 4500, 2960, Nortell(Avaya), Hp etc. I can easily use remote desktop application in that network using Windows and Mac OS X. For example my machine IP is let say 10.10.X.Y I can easily connect switch or desktop or server in lets say 10.30.Z.T or 10.10.K.L

Also one question is can I boot those computer  and install OS X? I mean no other person involve, just me boot remotely and install remotely.

Comment: The following ports have to be forwarded/relayed properly: bootpd (DHCP) – UDP 67, 68, tftpd (TFTP) – UDP 69 (**some of the following have to be accessible:** AppleFileServer (AFP) – TCP 548. nfsd (NFS) – TCP/UDP 2049, rpcbind (RPC) – TCP/UDP 111, NetInfo - TCP/UDP 600-1023, httpd (Web) – TCP 80)

Comment: I think these ports are in good position, but I will check them @klanomath

Comment: By the way we have too much switches, more than 600. Does it cause any problem? @klanomath

Comment: I don't think that number of switches/routers causes the problem

Comment: @klanomath I think the problem is causing from switches. We apply dhcp snooping to switches. So if we want to install Mac OS to local computers, we allow the port which Apple Server's connected and do not allow to take IP from the switch. So how can I do that in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to this party but @klanomath's comments are correct- you probably need to open the network ports. If you can see the images on the local network but not the remote network then it's likely the traffic isn't making it through.

Watch the server's system.log file for messages like this from bootpd:

```
BSDP INFORM [en0] 1,0:1b:63:39:d0:9f NetBoot024 arch=i386 sysid=iMac5,2
```

Or get a packet trace from the server:

```
sudo tcpdump -i en0 -s 0 -B 524288 -w ~/Desktop/NetBoot.pcap
```

I usually open them in Wireshark and filter for "bootp or tftp" to see how far things get. If there isn't any bootp traffic from that client then something on the network is probably blocking it.